# How to retrive data from ajax calling page and set it to textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Here I want to retrieve data from a page called using ajax call and set it as textbox value.I'm not so perfect with ajax but I've tried like this:

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left"> <label for="pat_id" >Patient ID</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="patient_id" id="patient_id"  readonly></td>
</tr>
```

Ajax call code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"retriveID.php",
    data: ({type: 'patient'}),
    success:function(html){ 
        $("#patient_id").html(html);        
    }
    });  
});
```

And retriveID.php:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$type = $_GET['type'];
if($type=='patient')
{
     $retrive_id=mysql_query("select patient_id from patient order by        patient_id desc limit 1") or die (mysql_error());
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($retrive_id);
     $patient_id="PAT".$row['0']+1;
}   

?>
```

I know this is not proper calling or requesting data.

Comment: `$("#patient_id").val(html);`

Comment: echo $patient_id at retriveID.php

Comment: also suggest me some sites where I can learn about AJAX as beginner and properly.

Comment: [Basics of jQuery AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 4):

Your have not echo your result.

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$type = $_GET['type'];
if($type=='patient')
{
     $retrive_id=mysql_query("select patient_id from patient order by        patient_id desc limit 1") or die (mysql_error());
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($retrive_id);
     $patient_id="PAT".$row['0']+1;
     echo  $patient_id;
}   
?>
```

and use

```
$("#patient_id").val(html);
```

Comment: if this answer is appropriate approve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo fetched value

```
echo $patient_id;
```

and then need to use [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) instead of `.html()` as `patient_id` is an input element.

```
$("#patient_id").val(html);
```

Comment: @DnyaneshwarChavan, Yes

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$("#patient_id").html(html);` with  `$("#patient_id").val(html);`